# Proving $EX=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\, dx$ when $X\geq0$

Tags: probability-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems on expected value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255937/problems-on-expected-value)

I have the following exercise I wish to solve:

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with distribution function $F$
>   and continuous density function $f$.
>
> Assume that $X$ is nonnegative; that is, $\forall x\leq0\, F(x)=0$.
>
> 1. Assume that $Ex<\infty$. Prove that $EX=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\, dx$
> 2. Assume that $Ex=\infty$. Prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\, dx=\infty$

**What I tried:**

Using integration by parts with $u=1-F(x),v'=1$ (hence $u'=-f(x),v=x)$
we get $$\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))\, dx=(1-F(x))x|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}-f(x)x\, dx$$

$$=(x-xF(x))|_{0}^{\infty}+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)x\, dx$$

$$=(x-xF(x))|_{0}^{\infty}+EX$$

Since $$(x-xF(x))|_{0}=0$$

we need to prove $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(1-F(x))=0$$ which I tried to show by L'Hôpital's rule and failed.

Can someone please help me continue with my way, or suggest another way to prove the requested equality ?

Comment: Please not this is just intro to probability, not the more advanced course with measure theory

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158206/expression-for-n-th-moment) for $n=1$.

Comment: I answered that question in great detail here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255937/problems-on-expected-value/256006#256006

Comment: @StefanHansen - I believe that post uses what I want to prove

Comment: @Learner - I looked at tht post at the link, but I didn't understand which one of the questions asked by the OP is my question. I also looked at your answer and didn't manage to understand which part is relevant to this question

Comment: Belgi: Fubini? $ $

Comment: @Belgi Take a special case of my answer. $X^- = 0$ a.s. and $p=1$, that gives the answer to question 1 (2 follows also from the Markov inequality in my answer there.

Comment: Belgi, the proof was however discussed in the comments. It leads to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/64199/25632) for example.

Comment: @StefanHansen - did's answer is way more advanced than what I know right now...the probability course I am taking is not about mwasure theory and is more basic.